# How to Connect Multiple Devices with the Same IP to a Windows PC

Tags: windows, networking, vlan

I'm working on a project that need to use a Windows PC/Server to control multiple identical devices through Ethernet. Obviously, those devices cannot be connected directly to the Windows PC/Server due to the IP conflicts.

This requirement seems can be easily met under Linux by using VLAN + network namespace (http://blog.scottlowe.org/2014/03/21/a-follow-up-on-linux-network-namespaces/), but unfortunately I have to stick to Windows.

I know there is a hardware solution for such cases:

Added routers (different IPs) between the Windows PC/Server and the devices and then configure port forwarding rules in the routers so that the Windows PC/Server can access to different devices via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx (router_ip:forwarded_device_port).

However, I'm still looking for a software solution under Windows, similar to what Linux can provide. Limited hardware is acceptable, such as added a VLAN tag switch.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Why can't you change the IP addresses on the devices to be unique? Seems very strange that a device designed to operate over ethernet would have a fixed, unchangeable IP.

Comment: Yes, the IP addresses can be changed but that means I have to change their IPs one by one rather than simply connecting them to the PC/Server. The number of the devices could be over 10,000, so I really don't want to go into that way. Actually, I've already implemented the desired function under Linux by using VLAN switch + network namespace. Just wondering if Windows can provide such simple software solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've got a switch setup accommodating 10,000 VLANs? Wow.

Comment: Obviously not 10,000 at a time, could be 20+. However, if I take the suggestion to change the IP addresses to avoid the conflict, doesn't that mean I need to reconfigure them all?

Comment: I am also trying to achieve this and I am wondering if you managed to get this working. If yes, could you please share with us how you did it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I work with some devices that are shipped with the same IP address and appear to be 'locked'. What we do is connect them to a separate laptop we have for this, with the IP settings configured so it connects to the device via a crossover cable. We can then log onto the device's web interface, and edit the IP configuration. Hopefully the same will work for you, unless the devices you're working with don't have any interface (or ssh, etc).